# Pure CSS solution to add multiple box shadows dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking to achieve this multiple underline effect and figured out that using box-shadows would be the best way to do it. Specifically, I tried doing this and was successful:

[image]

I used the following CSS to do it:

```css
h1{
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0px 0px #F03A47, 0 4px 0px 0px #FFF, 0 6px 0px #276FBF, 0 8px 0px 0px #FFF, 0 10px 0px #AF5B5B;
    float: left;
}
```

However, I'd like to achieve an effect to turn specific underlines on and off as required. So I came up with this and added the classes to my HTML:

```css
h1{
    float: left;
}
.red{
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0px 0px #F03A47, 0 4px 0px 0px #FFF;
}
.blue{
    box-shadow: 0 6px 0px #276FBF, 0 8px 0px 0px #FFF;
}
.brown{
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0px #AF5B5B, 0 12px 0px 0px #FFF;
}
```

But the effect that it produced was this:

[image]

I tried adding the classes in different orders and also adding them dynamically using JavaScript, but I am still getting the same result. Am I doing anything wrong, or is there an alternative way to achieve the turn-on turn-off effect?

Comment: so clearly the white stripes (using `#fff`) are not an option... right?

Comment: You can't do them separately like that but you can make CSS selectors for the combinations like `.red.blue`, `.red.blue.brown`, `.red.brown`, `.blue.brown`, etc. Also, I haven't tried it for `box-shadow`, but you can see if [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) will allow you to shorthand the values for each class.

Comment: Would it be ok to call a function which adds the box shadows based on the parameters that were passed in? e.g. `addUnderlines(['red', 'blue'])`

Comment: @David even if, you cannot create transparent gaps.

Comment: Please review and comment on any answer, and let us know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An interesting way using `<span>`s :)

You can add as many `<span>` as you want and just extend the colors palette in CSS:

```css
.borders {
  display: inline-block;
}
.borders span {
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.borders span:nth-child(1) { background: red; }
.borders span:nth-child(2) { background: blue; }
.borders span:nth-child(3) { background: green; }
/* Add more here */
```

```html
<h1 class="borders">
  Hi there
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</h1>
```

Or if you need only 3 borders and you don't want to insert additional HTML elements:

use a `border-bottom` for your first class, than `:before` on your second class and `:after` on your third class.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.red{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 red;
}

.blue:after, .green:before{ content: ""; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0; }

.blue:after{
  bottom: -6px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.green:before{
  bottom: -10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="red blue green">Hi there</h1>
```

Comment: The <hr> thing is basically the same as using tables for layout. But what makes it worse still is that, unlike layout tables, it's not even valid.

Comment: @bolt thanks. HR is absolutely permitted inside flow elements. H1 is such element. A block element. Although browser style rules are not defined you can actually style a HR tag. I should have used SPAN indeed, but here you go. Could not find any valid argument on HR not being allowed or deprecated as such beside being a semantical "separator" Any thoughts?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements "Content model: Phrasing content." So HR is not allowed in H1, because H1's content model does not expect flow elements.

Answer (score 18):

This could be accomplished with [pseudo elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp):

```css
h1 {
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:2px solid #e8353b;
  position:relative;
}
  h1:before {
    content:"";
    height:2px;
    width:100%;
    background:#2762be;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-6px;
  }
  h1:after {
    content:"";
    height:2px;
    width:100%;
    background:#a3514f;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Hello there</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `linear-gradient`, which will be fully transparent.

*Note, when combine classes as you did, they doesn't **merge** those values, the last property set on an element will overwrite any previous, whether they are set in classes with different names or not, hence your **line** becomes all brown.*

```css
body {
  background: lightgray
}

h1{
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background-size: 100% 2px;                         /* thickness 2px */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 
      left bottom, left bottom 4px, left bottom 8px;   /* gutter 2px */ 
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, blue, blue),           /* bottom line */
      linear-gradient(to right, green, green),         /* middle line */
      linear-gradient(to right, red, red);             /* top line */
  }
  
h1.red{
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, blue, blue), 
      linear-gradient(to right, green, green),      
      linear-gradient(to right, transparent,transparent);
}
h1.blue{
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, transparent,transparent),
      linear-gradient(to right, green, green),      
      linear-gradient(to right, red, red);      
}
h1.green{
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, blue, blue), 
      linear-gradient(to right, transparent,transparent),
      linear-gradient(to right, red, red);      
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello there</h1>

<h1 class="green">Hello there</h1>

<h1 class="red">Hello there</h1>

<h1 class="blue">Hello there</h1>
```

---

You can easily re-position the lines and close any gap by simply leave out the line you don't want.

```css
body {
  background: lightgray
}

h1{
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background-size: 100% 2px;                         /* thickness 2px */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 
      left bottom, left bottom 4px, left bottom 8px;   /* gutter 2px */ 
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, blue, blue),           /* bottom line */
      linear-gradient(to right, green, green),         /* middle line */
      linear-gradient(to right, red, red);             /* top line */
  }
  
h1.red{
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, blue, blue), 
      linear-gradient(to right, green, green);     
}
h1.blue{
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, green, green),      
      linear-gradient(to right, red, red);      
}
h1.green{
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(to right, blue, blue), 
      linear-gradient(to right, red, red);      
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello there</h1>

<h1 class="green">Hello there</h1>

<h1 class="red">Hello there</h1>

<h1 class="blue">Hello there</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this with only 1 pseudo-element.

Here's what I've done (with comments on how to control spacings):

```css
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    /* controls the last line */
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a3514f;
}

h1:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    /* controls space between 1st and 2nd line */
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    /* controls space between 2nd and 3rd line */
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2762be;
    border-top: 2px solid #e8353b;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello there</h1>
```

---

This was written based on [@APAD1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44788621/2729937), taking his idea of using borders.

This method offers the advantage of the whole `::after` being part of the content of the `<h1>`, instead of being outside.

Comment: OP asked for: *`However, I'd like to achieve an effect to turn specific underlines on and off as required.`*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Remove borders. Easy. Or control the border height with classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add up to five lines using pseudoelements and borders.

Each class adds a new line.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 6px;
  bottom: -10px;
}
h1:after {
  bottom: -18px;
}
.one {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
.two:before {
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}
.three:before {
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
.four:after {
  border-top: 2px solid brown;
}
.five:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="one two three four five">Lorem ipsum</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to get as many lines as posible, using pseudos, borders, shadows ...

You get up to 9 lines, that can be set / unset with 9 independent classes.

Some of them need will only work against a solid, known background-color (white in this case)

```css
.base {
  font-size: 60px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.base:before,
.base:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.base:before {
  bottom: -90px;
}
.base:after {
  bottom: -170px;
}

.a {
  border-bottom: solid 10px lightgreen;
}

.b {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px white, 0px 20px green;
}

.c:before {
  border-top: solid 10px lightblue;
}

.d:before {
  background-color: red;
}

.e:before {
  border-bottom: solid 10px yellow;
}

.f:before {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px white, 0px 20px green;
}

.g:after {
  border-top: solid 10px tomato;
}

.h:after {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.i:after {
  border-bottom: solid 10px gray;
}

.j:after {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px white, 0px 20px brown;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="base a b c d e f g h i j">Hello world</h1>
```